# Passing a method to a backgroundworker dowork

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

In the code below, is there a way to instead of always subscribing the updateWorker_DoWork method, pass it a method like this

```
public void GetUpdates(SomeObject blah)
{
    //...
    updateWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(blah);
    //...
}


public void GetUpdates()
{
    //Set up worker
    updateWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    updateWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    updateWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(updateWorker_DoWork);
    updateWorker.RunWorkerCompleted +=
        new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(updateWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
    updateWorker.ProgressChanged +=
        new ProgressChangedEventHandler(updateWorker_ProgressChanged);

    //Run worker
    _canCancelWorker = true;
    updateWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    //Initial Progress zero percent event
    _thes.UpdateProgress(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For your `RunWorkerAsync()` you can pass any argument you like. You can just put a `Func()` or `Action()` into it and in your `DoWork()` you just cast the object back to this specific type and call it.

Examples are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902384/make-a-backgroundworker-do-several-operations-sequentially-without-freezing-the-f/1907501#1907501) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183520/backgroundworkers-never-stop-being-busy/2183963#2183963).

```
private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
{
    _Worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    // On a call cast the e.Argument to a Func<TResult> and call it...
    // Take the result from it and put it into e.Result
    _Worker.DoWork += (sender, e) => e.Result = ((Func<string>)e.Argument)();

    // Take the e.Result and print it out
    // (cause we will always call a Func<string> the e.Result must always be a string)
    _Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Debug.Print((string)e.Result);
    };
}

private void StartTheWorker()
{
    int someValue = 42;

    //Take a method with a parameter and put it into another func with no parameter
    //This is called currying or binding
    StartTheWorker(new Func<string>(() => DoSomething(someValue)));

   while(_Worker.IsBusy)
       Thread.Sleep(1);

   //If your function exactly matches, just put it into the argument.
   StartTheWorker(AnotherTask);
}

private void StartTheWorker(Func<string> func)
{
    _Worker.RunWorkerAsync(func);
}

private string DoSomething(int value)
{
    return value.ToString("x");
}

private string AnotherTask()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So what would the argument type be if I wanted to pass the delegate into the StartTheWorker function. Essentially I want to be able to call StartTheWorker(DoSomething) and have DoSomething run as a background worker

Comment: @James: That's just another wrapper to be built up with `Func()`. I updated the example to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

If I didn't misunderstand you, you need lambda expressions to construct anonymous method.

```
updateWorker.DoWork += (sender,e)=>
  {
      //bla
  }
```

Now you needn't always to write a method and pass it to `new DoWorkEventHandler(myMethod)`

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out, was way simpler than I was thinking. Just had to make a delegate for the method called on DoWork. Probably should have phrased my original question better.

```
    public delegate void DoWorkDelegate(object sender,DoWorkEventArgs e);

     public void GetUpdates()
     {
         StartWorker(new DoWorkDelegate(updateWorker_DoWork));
     }

     public void StartWorker(DoWorkDelegate task)
     {
         //Set up worker
         updateWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
         updateWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
         updateWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(task);
         updateWorker.RunWorkerCompleted +=
             new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(updateWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
         updateWorker.ProgressChanged +=
             new ProgressChangedEventHandler(updateWorker_ProgressChanged);

         //Run worker
         _canCancelWorker = true;
         updateWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
         //Initial Progress zero percent event
         _thes.UpdateProgress(0);
     }

      private void updateWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
      {
          BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
          e.Result = GetUpdatesTask(worker, e);
      }
```