# Synchronize background worker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, .net-4.5

I have a code like this:

```
if (condition#1) {
   // step 2
   ConfigurazioneSA csa = new ConfigurazioneSA(...);
   WconfiguraSA.RunWorkerAsync(csa);
}
else
{
   // step 1
   PassaggioIE bo = new PassaggioIE(...);
   WpassIE.RunWorkerAsync(bo);

   if (condition#2) {
      // step 2
      ConfigurazioneSA csa = new ConfigurazioneSA(...);
      WconfiguraSA.RunWorkerAsync(csa);
   }
}
```

When execution flow is inside `condition#1` branch, the `step 1` block has been previously executed (in a previous execution of my application) so `step 2` can be executed without any problem.

But, when execution flow is inside `else` branch I need to execute `step 1` and when this step is completed I can execute `step 2`. Since I'm using `BackgroundWorker` as step 1 start, `step 2`starts immediately after causing error.

I would sinchronize this producer/consumer problem adding as less entropy as I can. All solutions that I found introduce a great amount of code, while I would a simply semaphore that avoid the `step 2` execution until `step 1` is not complete. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IsBusy` example:

```cs
else
{
   // step 1
   PassaggioIE bo = new PassaggioIE(...);
   WpassIE.RunWorkerAsync(bo);

   // wait for WpassIE to complete
   while(WpassIE.IsBusy) Application.DoEvents();

   if (condition#2) {
      // step 2
      ConfigurazioneSA csa = new ConfigurazioneSA(...);
      WconfiguraSA.RunWorkerAsync(csa);
   }
}
```

In this solution, you've to wait WpassIE completion.

and don't use `Thread.Sleep` instead of `Application.DoEvents` because it causes problem like [BackgroundWorkers never stop being busy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183520/backgroundworkers-never-stop-being-busy).

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you to use `Tpl` for this. This can be achieved easily.

```
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        //Step1
    }).ContinueWith(antecedent =>  //executed after step1 is done
    {
        if (condition#2) 
        {
        // step 2
        }
    });
```

Also note you'll not get events like `Progress` and `Completed`, you've to sacrifice.  `Completed` event is similar to `ContinuationTask`.

One more difference here is `ContinuationTask` will execute in threadpool thread, If you want it in UI thread use `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`

Comment: I've insert your code inside my else branch and then replace step1 and step2 with real code but seems already not in synchro :(

Comment: I can't get you, What happens?

Comment: Nothing. As soon step1 starts step2 starts too (causing the same error like before)...

Comment: Replace step1 and step2 with codes in `DoWork` handlers, not `RunWorkerAsync`.

Comment: yes unarist is right, You've to use the code in `DoWork` in step1

Comment: This means that I should remove the previous event handling (from the doWork), and this will add entropy. What could I use to localize (as much as I can) the editing to that if/else branch?

Comment: In multithreaded application you can't expect anything to be synchronous. You can't guarantee that when if/else execute your `operation2` has finished executed already. Best way is to start async operations, then continue when async operation is done(that's what I provided as a solution).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Tasks, you can use [`BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event raised when its execution is completed.

```cs
// step 1
PassaggioIE bo = new PassaggioIE(...);

WpassIE.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) => {

    // You might want to add error handling code here.

    if (condition#2) {
        // step 2
        ConfigurazioneSA csa = new ConfigurazioneSA(...);
        WconfiguraSA.RunWorkerAsync(csa);
    }
}

WpassIE.RunWorkerAsync(bo);
```

But I think using TPL is better too.

Comment: does the bo.RunWorkerCompleted create a mess with previously RunWorkerCompleted?

Comment: Oops, I thought `bo` is BackgroundWorker... If you use same BackgroundWorker many times, that's right.

Comment: For workaround, save lambda expression as delegate, then you can remove it from `RunWorkerCompleted`. If you can block this method while step1, `BackgroundWorker.IsBusy` is useful.

Comment: Should I write something like `while(!BackgroundWorker.IsBusy) {// step 2}`

Comment: Like `while(!BackgroundWorker.IsBusy) Application.DoEvents();`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183520/backgroundworkers-never-stop-being-busy.

Comment: It never goes inside the while? It looks like Background is stuck in busy mode! :(

Comment: oh...I made a mistake again. I'll write as new answer.